# Is it possible to setup a color for a specific word in visual studio 9?

Tags: visual-studio, color-scheme

I have to use a lot of specific variables at my work (like T_ULONG or T_SWORD) and I'd like them to be displayed as variables (blue color or whatever). It's quite annoying to have whole pieces of code in black and white ... 
I saw that there were a lot of themes for VS, but these won't solve my problem...

Any clues ? Thanks for reading anyway :)

Answer (score 9):

Assuming you're talking about C/C++, yes:

Create a file called usertype.dat containing your keywords (one per line) and save it into C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE or equivalent.

In VS, go Tools / Options / Fonts and Colors / Text Editor and in the Display Items list select User Keywords.  Set your colours, OK the dialog, and restart VS.